# Issue with storing cocos2d game configuration in sqlite + coredata

Tags: iphone, sqlite, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

in my previous cocos2d game i had limited number of levels so i had made separate class files for each levels `(.h and .m)`

but now in my current game im having large number of levels so i felt that having individual files is not a good idea.

so i decided to store all level's configuration in sqlite and build levels by fetching data from it.

but as i'm using Box2d with cocos2d it is now becoming more complex to handle all bodies, joins, positions with single code which is iterating bodies from sqlite. is sqlite proper option or should i go back with seperate classes for each levels??

Answer (score 0):

one of our game have about 150 levels and still we handle all this with plist.
Just create a generic dictionary for a level and add all levels to plist in form of dictionaries.
And in code side, write a level handler through which you can load a level from plist.